# Is it possible to create an iCal stream from Open Atrium's calendar feature? If so, how?

Tags: 6, distributions

I'm getting mixed signals around whether or not its possible to create an iCal feed from the Open Atrium Calendar Feature.

When I try creating a new view or adding a feed to an existing view, I don't see the option for an iCal feed...just RSS :(

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Some background: http://drupal.org/node/348871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making the feed in a custom module using the [iCalCreator](http://kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/#.UCUQQ01lSf8) library. I did like this approach because I was able to be very selective with the events to include in the feed which was a requirement and the iCalCreator library was VERY easy to work with :D

Comment: Would you be open to sharing this custom module?

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer work for the company that did this site so I don't have access to the source code :(

Comment: Ah, that's a shame.  I guess I'll have to start from scratch.

Comment: Using the iCalCreator library it was a straight-forward process. Keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module provides this feature, and that it is part of Open Atrium, I think. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... will display any Views date field in calendar formats, including CCK date fields, node created or updated dates, etc. Switch between year, month, and day views. Back and next navigation is provided for all views. Lots of the Calendar functionality comes from the Date module, so any time you update the Calendar module you should be sure you also update to the latest version of the Date module at the same time.
>
> See also [Date iCal](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_ical), a project that contains code and features needed to either import or export dates using iCal feeds. The functionality that used to be in the Calendar iCal module has been moved into that module.

Comment: I think the Open Atrium install of the Calendar "feature" does something to the views that prevents iCal creation without altering the feature or view. I ended up using the PHP iCalCreator library and writing a custom module. Worked out better for us in the end anyway..